# Telegraf output plugin to submit metric to datadog agent

Tags: datadog, telegraf, telegraf-output-plugins

Is anyone aware if there is any telegraf output plugin to submit metric to datadog agent? I can see a [datadog output plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/datadog) which calls datadog metric api but not anything to submit data to datadog agent.